# I want YTD amount for each category in my MDX query

Tags: ssas, mdx, bids

I've one MDX query where i want to show each of my product month wise count and along with that want to show YTD, MTD, WTD etc.

I've first created following MDx query on Adventure Works which give me YTD but its shows each months. instead i need output as below and I want to  provide current month+year(Mar 2015) in MDX filter or where clause

EXPECTED Results:

```
Category    YTD 
---------   ------
Bike        4500
Accessories 78000
Clothing     8900
```

Can you please correct below MDX query to get above results sets

```
SELECT
    {
    ([Product].[Category].CHILDREN,[Measures].[Order Quantity])
    } ON 0,

    {
    YTD([Date].[Calendar].[Month].[August 2008])
    } ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

or i've built another MDX query which give same results either one should be corrected to show above EXPECTED results.

```
SELECT
    {
    ([Product].[Category].CHILDREN ,[Measures].[Order Quantity])
    } ON Axis(0),

    {
    PERIODSTODATE([Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year],[Date].[Calendar].[Month].[August 2008])
    } ON Axis (1)
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I have the same version of the AW cube as you (or what version of SSAS you are using), but try this. In the 2014 multidimensional cube, I have to change the measure to Order Count rather than quantity and change the date to March 2012 to get data back.

```
WITH MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[CalendarYTD] AS
    Aggregate(
        YTD([Date].[Calendar].[Month].[March 2015])
    )
SELECT 
    [Date].[Calendar].[CalendarYTD] ON COLUMNS,
    [Product].[Category].Children ON ROWS
FROM
    [Adventure Works]
WHERE
    [Measures].[Order Quantity]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked very well with my query too. would you be able to help to get total days count of this YTD. I want to show total days considered in this YTd calculation as well.